# splitting multiple joined words, port from perl to PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, strings, parsing, perl

Though i have never worked on perl, not even once. 
I have ported the perl code into PHP and it seems like giving a correct result. But as I am going to use it on production server.

I want this code to get it reviewed, please let me know if there is any problem in the porting from perl to PHP.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $WORD_FILE = '/usr/share/dict/words'; #Change as needed
my %words; # Hash of words in dictionary

# Open dictionary, load words into hash
open(WORDS, $WORD_FILE) or die "Failed to open dictionary: $!\n";
while (<WORDS>) {
  chomp;
  $words{lc($_)} = 1;
}
close(WORDS);

# Read one line at a time from stdin, break into words
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @words;
  find_words(lc($_));
}

sub find_words {
  # Print every way $string can be parsed into whole words
  my $string = shift;
  my @words = @_;
  my $length = length $string;

  foreach my $i ( 1 .. $length ) {
    my $word = substr $string, 0, $i;
    my $remainder = substr $string, $i, $length - $i;
    # Some dictionaries contain each letter as a word
    next if ($i == 1 && ($word ne "a" && $word ne "i"));

    if (defined($words{$word})) {
      push @words, $word;
      if ($remainder eq "") {
        print join(' ', @words), "\n";
        return;
      } else {
        find_words($remainder, @words);
      }
      pop @words;
    }
  }

  return;
}
```

The PHP code which I want a review on:

```
<?php

$WORD_FILE = file_get_contents ("word.txt") ;

$temp_arr = explode("\n", $WORD_FILE);

foreach ($temp_arr as $str)
{
    $words [$str] = 1 ;
}

$processed = Array () ;

find_words ($argv[1]) ; 
print_r ($processed) ;

function find_words ($str)
{
    global $words ;
    global $processed ;

    $string = $str ;
    $length = strlen ($str) ;

    for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $length + 1; $i++)
    {
        $word = substr ($string, 0, $i) ;
        $remainder = substr ($string, $i, $length - $i) ;

        if ($i == 1 && ($word != "a" && $word != "i")) ;

        if (array_key_exists ($word, $words))
        {
            array_push($processed, $word) ;
            if ($remainder == "")
            {
                return ;
            }
            else
            {
                find_words ($remainder, $words) ;
            }
            echo "popping the word " . array_pop ($words) . "\n";
        }
    }

    return ;
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You're mostly interested in just having the PHP reviewed, correct? It sounded like that, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, I want to know whether the PHP code will work correctly and give correct results or not.

Comment: Ouch! However, despite its glam looks it doesn't work. I'm working on a post

Comment: Your original Perl still needs a lot of work, and I am struggling to believe that you didn't know that. If you're having trouble getting it going, then you should post it on Stack Overflow instead, together with your sample input, and required and actual output

Answer (score 1):

This should be `find_words()` php equivalent,
(note perl `%words` is here `$Gwords` as perl makes distinction between hashes/dictionaries and arrays)

```
function find_words() {
    global $Gwords;

    # Print every way $string can be parsed into whole words
    $words = func_get_args();
    $string = array_shift($words);
    $length = strlen($string);

    foreach (range(1, $length) as $i) {

        $word = substr($string, 0, $i);
        $remainder = substr($string, $i, $length - $i);
        # Some dictionaries contain each letter as a word
        if ($i == 1 && ($word !== "a" && $word !== "i")) continue;

        if (isset($Gwords[$word])) {
            $words[]= $word;
            if ($remainder === "") {
                echo join(' ', $words), "\n";
                return;
            }
            else {
                # find_words($remainder, @words);
                call_user_func_array(
                    "find_words",
                    array_merge((array)$remainder, $words)
                );
            }
            array_pop($words);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I use this file in place of `/usr/share/dict/words`

#### words.txt

```
a
ab
abc
i
ij
ijk
x
xy
xyz
```

and this file as input

#### input.txt

```
Adam
Abacab
Nnapric
Alejandro
Dillijence
Alicia
Ambrose
Caleb
Abbey
xyzygy
```

Then your Perl code produces no output at all. As far as I can tell, these "words" should be found

```
a
ab
i
ij
xy
xyz
```

There is absolutely no point in asking for a code review of a translation of a non-functional program